# programming WHERE section in sql

Tags: php, sql

Example i'm getting 2 variable from my db.($v1, $v2)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=$1 AND  $v2
```

But in another example im getting 3 variable from db ($v1, $v2, $v3)at same query cause i proggramed it like it. In this condition how can i program WHERE statement of sql query

**edit**

```
WHERE id=$v1 AND $v2 AND $v3 // i want to add it And conditions automaticly
```

Comment: You want to know if `id` is equal to more than one value?  What's in `$v2` or `$v3`?  Are you adding SQL string conditions in those variables?  Or actual data?

Comment: `id=x and y` doesn't make much sense. Is `id` supposd to be equal to both of those value, or should `id` be equal to the logical AND of the two values?

Comment: I never use AND condition shoul i write id=$v2 again.whatever this is not the question the question is how can i program in a sql query

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select multiple ID values, use IN conditional:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ($v1, $v2, $v3)`

EDIT: Asked for a flexible way to add values:

Assuming that this query is set by a function and this function will receive all ID values that should be in where clause. Something like:

```
<?php

$example_ids = array(1, 5, 7, 15, 22);

wherein($example_ids)

function wherein($ids){
    // Select part
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable ";

    // Where statement
    $where = " WHERE id IN (";

    // For loop to use each value sent
    // as a value in IN (...
    for ($i=0; $i < count($ids); $i++) { 
        // Eg: $i = 0
        // $ids[$i] = 1
        // 
        // So:
        // WHERE id IN (1
        $where .= $ids[$i];

        // If its not the last value then
        // add a comma for SQL syntax
        if ($i < count($ids) - 1)
            /// Where id IN (1,
            $where .= ",";
    }

    // At the end of the loop, $where must be
    // something like:
    // WHERE id IN (1,5,7,15,22
    // 
    // Once again, for SQL syntax, the close )
    $where .= ")";

    // Finaly, the last step, putting all together:
    // SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE id IN (1,5,7,15,22)
    $query .= $where;
}
```

Comment: But another time i ll get 8 value and i want to put them right there with a program in sql query how can i do that

Comment: Then you must: 

1. Organize ids in an array
2. In a for loop, concatenate each variable with a comma
3. Check for the last value to prevent SQL syntax error
4. Close where clausule
5. Concatenate major query with this where variable.

I'll update the code.

Comment: Okay i get the your answer IN is what i need. update the code

Comment: Have in mind that you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection. I believe that you can adapt a similar solution with that. Read more about at: http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find any records which contain any of your variable you can use `OR` as follow

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = $v1 OR id = $v2 OR id = $v3
```

Comment: Okay i ll use OR butb real question is different

Comment: What's real question then?

Comment: Isnt my question clear? another time i ll get 8 value and another just 2 again i want to add it this or conditions automaticly

Comment: Man you need to elaborate your code, maybe create an array of ids and loop throw it and build the query according

Comment: How to loop in an sql query